# Would you please explain to me the morphology of the word retroviral?

Tags: grammar, etymology, orthography, suffixes, morphology

I cannot understand the morphology of the word retroviral.

> is "re" the prefix?

- I think the prefix might be retro, is that true?

> is "al the suffix?

- I am assuming that "viral" is the root, is that true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**retrovirus (noun) retroviral (adjective)**

The prefix **"retro-"** has been added to **"virus"** because of the retrograde mechanism used for replication.

> - "Once inside the host cell cytoplasm, the virus uses its own reverse transcriptase enzyme to produce DNA from its RNA genome, the reverse of the usual pattern, thus retro (backwards)."   - from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrovirus)

[retrograde](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrograde) - "moving, occurring, or performed in a backward direction"

[retro](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/retro-)  (pref.)   "contrary to a usual or natural course or direction: retrograde."

Comment: "viral" is the adjective form of "virus". It's not a suffix, its just the way that the word "virus" is converted into an adjective.

Comment: I can't write it in tree form, but using parentheses to group as in mathematics, it's (retro + virus) + al, with -al a common adjective-forming suffix (sometimes coming to us from Latin words with the suffix -alis), as in "causal", "usual", "bridal", "oral" (Latin "os" = "mouth", stem form "or-"), "arboreal", etc.

Answer (score 0):

As also stated in the other answer I see at the moment of writing here, the word retro in Latin means a movement backwards or a backward position, both in time and place. A quote from the Gospel is "Vade retro Satana" (Back away, Devil!), spoken by Jesus in the desert to the Devil who wanted to tempt him.

> Go back, Satan!
>   An exhortation for Satan to be gone, often used in response to temptation. From a popular Medieval Catholic exorcismformula, based on a rebuke by Jesus to Peter in the Vulgate, Mark 8:33: vade retro me Satana |"step back from me, Satan!"|. The older phrase vade retro |"go back!"| can be found in Terence's Formio I, 4, 203. 
>   https://glosbe.com/la/en/vade%20retro%20Satana

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.